# Sum the occurrence of a string

Tags: excel

If I have a column with boys and girls and I want to count for example the number of boys, what can I do? I guess it would be a combination of sum and if or something. Honestly don't know.

Comment: First of all, you have to show us what you have tried before. Second, there is a `COUNT()` function in Excel. Third, you could have googled that.

Comment: I honestly have no idea what to do, I tried to google it first and I didn't find anything (still searching)

Comment: Please add a textual example of you data.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution:  =COUNTIF(the column,"Man").. The problem was that I didn't use quotation marks

Comment: then, depending on your data you can use countifs() and count men after a certain birth date or from a particular country or county etc etc